# How can I calculate the difference in Minutes between 2 Timestamp-variables in BigQuery? (Standard SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, timestampdiff

I have 2 columns started_at and ended_at (both timestamps) and try to calculate the exact difference in minutes, but somehow it dont wanna work.
I've already looked for similar questions but it doesnt work for me..

| started_at | ended_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 16:22:53 UTC | 2021-01-02 16:43:40 UTC |
| ... | ... |

**What I have tried:**

```
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_ymd,
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,
    EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_ymd,
    EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time
```

Results are in yyyy-mm-dd format but I dont know what to do with these extracts.

The **standard method** below works well with 2 single timestamps:

```
SELECT 

    TIMESTAMP("2010-07-07 10:20:00+00") AS later_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 15:30:00+00") AS earlier_timestamp,

    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP "2010-07-07 10:20:00+00", TIMESTAMP "2008-12-25 15:30:00+00", HOUR) AS hours;
```

But I have **2 columns** with millions of data and I dont know how to calculate each timediff.
Thanks a lot guys, I am dealing with this little problem since 6 hours smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "standard method" you mentioned should work fine, you just need to put a table name in (your query as it stands diffs two contant values and hence returns one single result):

```
SELECT  
  started_at, 
  ended_at,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(started_at, ended_at, MINUTE) AS minutes_between
FROM
  yourtablenamehere
```

Used on a 2 million row table called `yourtablenamehere` it produces 2 million timestamp diffs - run with care

Comment: OMG, I have tried this type of code a million times but got allways an error. Your Code works well. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'd recommend posting up any such attempts and the error messages, so we can tell you where you go wrong - it sounds like you were very close to a solution, maybe just some missing bracket or something

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, minute)`

Official documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff)